# why cant I access array outside this loop

Tags: java, arrays

when the array is printed outside only my last element gets printed. I have been struggling with this since a long time please help me I am really weak in java

```
for (int i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    Rectangle current = arr[i];
    a1=new int[]{ current.area() };
    System.out.println("a1 area" + Arrays.toString(a1));
    System.out.println("------------------------------------");
    Arrays.sort(a1);
}
System.out.println("outside" + Arrays.toString(a1));
```

Comment: `a1` only exists in the scope of the for-loop.

Comment: Where is a1 declared?

Comment: @August, a1 initialized inside the for loop. But it may be declared outside of the for loop - at least from this code it's seems a1 is initialized outside of the for loop block.

Comment: above for loop. i am trying to store arrays inside a1 but when i print inside the loop i get a[1],a[2] instead of a[1,2] why is that

Comment: I don't understand your purpose. If you try to display the last position, its done (last println in loop); if you try to display the first overflow position, its not existing (arr overflow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this doesn't do what you want

```
int[] a1 = new int[arr.length]; //a1 is an array of areas

for (int i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     Rectangle current = arr[i];
     a1[i] = current.area();
     System.out.println("a1 area: " + a1[i]); //TODO remove debugging code
     System.out.println("------------------------------------"); 
}
Arrays.sort(a1);

System.out.println("outside" + Arrays.toString(a1));
```

`a1` will have the same length as `arr` because each `Rectangle` has one area.  I saved sorting until outside the loop since it's not doing you any good sorting each iteration if you aren't doing anything with it.  Sort it once before you print it.

By the way, `a1` and `arr` are horrible names.  `areas` and `rectangles` would be much better.

UPDATE:

One of the critical flaws of the original code was this line:

```
a1=new int[]{ current.area() };
```

That line was in a loop getting a new `current` each time, getting the area from it, and packing it in a one element array. But each one-element-array-of-area reference was stored in the same place, `a1`.  Than ment each time the loop came around again the old one got stepped on by the new one.  Sorting each one-element-array didn't do anything to fix this.

Comment: u are right it worked but why wasnt mine working...can u please xplain

Comment: @STRANGER how's that?

Comment: @STRANGER this will really help you understand why you weren't able to access your array outside of the loop: http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html. 
It's pretty essential in programming to understand what 'variable scope' is.